# Metal: Writing to a texture and reading it without calling endEncoding

Tags: ios, metal

Problem: I have some shapes drawn on a surface(**S0**), I want to take a new Surface(**S1**), render some more shapes with alpha on **S1**, and finally composite them on **S0**.

Solution: A simple solution, would be to:

1. Create an `id<MTLTexture> t1`, set it as the color attachment to the `MTLRenderCommandEncoder r1`, to create S0.
2. Draw all the shapes that have to be drawn on S0.
3. Call `endEncoding` on `r1` and create a new `id<MTLTexture> t2`, and set it as the color attachment to `MTLRenderCommandEncoder r2`, to create S1.
4. Draw all shapes to be drawn on S1. Call `endEncoding` on `r2`.
5. Again create a new `MTLRenderCommandEncoder r3`, this time with color attachment as `t1`, and draw the content of `t2` on `t1`.
6. And finally, call `endEncoding`.

As you can see, I had to call `endEncoding` 3 times. And from my experience, more the `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`s you have in your code, worse is your performance.

**Ques:** Is there any way I can improve the performance of this? Or reduce the number of `endEncoding`s, to get better performance?

This is how I create `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`:

```
MTLRenderPassDescriptor* renderPassDescriptor = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor];
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture // (an id<MTLTexture>)
descriptor.storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;
descriptor.loadAction = MTLLoadActionLoad;
descriptor.clearColor = clearColor; // MTLClearColor
```

Then create an encoder using:

```
renderEncoder = [_commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
```

Comment: What prevents you from rendering S1 in the first pass, then drawing S0 and compositing S1 atop S0 in a second pass? Even if drawing and compositing use different render pipeline states, it seems you could combine those commands into a single pass.

Comment: @warrenm when you say in a single pass, you mean in a single command buffer?!

Comment: Also, from what I observe, creating multiple render command encoders significantly decreased the total performance, for almost 1000 such switches, my application became unresponsive.

Comment: When I say a single pass, I mean a single render command encoder.

Comment: I'm not surprised you found running 1,000 passes per frame to be untenable. Even the most sophisticated AAA games tend to use on the order of 100 passes per frame. I can scarcely imagine a scenario where you would, fundamentally, need to switch attachment sets that many times to compose a frame.

Comment: @warrenm Apparently, I do need to switch unless I modify my algorithm. This switch was so fast and efficient in OpenGL, but is a real killer in Metal. I wonder, how OpenGL could make it fast.